# Cannot pass parameter by reference

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a PHP installer for a project I am working on. When I hit the submit button on my installer, it causes this error to show up:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference.

**Code:**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `email`, `password`, `name`, `token_code`, `email_activation_code`, `lost_password_code`, `facebook_id`, `type`, `active`, `language`, `date`, `ip`, `last_activity`, `last_user_agent`, `total_logins`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssss", '1', $adminEmail, $adminPass, $adminUsername, '', '', '', '', '1', '1', 'english',);

$adminEmail = $_POST['admin-email'];
$adminUsername = $_POST['admin-username'];
$adminPass = password_hash($_POST['admin-password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here, because `bind_param()` requires all its arguments be passed by reference (except the first arg which is the control string).

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssss", '1', $adminEmail, $adminPass, $adminUsername, 
  '', '', '', '', '1', '1', 'english',);
```

String literals like `'1'` are not lvalues, so they cannot be passed by reference.

You can fix it this way:

```
$one = '1';
$blank = '';
$english = 'english';

$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssss", $one, $adminEmail, $adminPass, $adminUsername, 
  $blank, $blank, $blank, $blank, $one, $one, $english);
```

---

If it were me, I'd use PDO instead of mysqli. PDO has an easier method of passing parameters. No binding step necessary. Just pass as an array to `execute()`, and this accepts non-lvalues:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(...);
$stmt->execute([
  '1', $adminEmail, $adminPass, $adminUsername, '', '', '', '1', '1', 'english'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind_param only accepts variables and not '' or '1'

so define a variable and add it to bind_param,

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `email`, `password`, `name`, `token_code`, `email_activation_code`, `lost_password_code`, `facebook_id`, `type`, `active`, `language`, `date`, `ip`, `last_activity`, `last_user_agent`, `total_logins`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$emptvar = '';
$one = '1';
$language = 'english';
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssss", $one, $adminEmail, $adminPass, $adminUsername, $emptvar , $emptvar , $emptvar , $emptvar , $one, $one, $language,);

$adminEmail = $_POST['admin-email'];
$adminUsername = $_POST['admin-username'];
$adminPass = password_hash($_POST['admin-password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$stmt->execute();
```